# Problem installing graphics driver on machine with Nvidia GeForce RTX 3050

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound, graphics, fonts

I have bought a new PC , and I am relatively new to Linux, but not completely new. I had been tinkering with it on my Raspberry pi. I am not pleased to the way Microsoft and Apple are moving forward with new products, and thought having Linux on the new computer is or would be a way to migrate slowly to having Linux as primary use system. MacOs is currently my primary use system.
I am an artist so Ubuntu Studio distro was best choice. The shop owner built the PC I requested from a list of parts. It dual boots with Windows 11.

I noticed that the Nvidia driers hadn't been installed, so I naturally thought I go and browse to install the Nvidia drivers. Because I need the drivers because the sound plays out through the HDMI through the screen.

When I installed the drivers( not to sure if drivers are card specific and not like windows where the Nvidia installer covers all possible supported  Nvidia cards.

After the installation through command line which I copied and pasted from a website on how to install Nvidia drivers , rebooted and when I rebooted. The driver was well the sound through the HDMI was working but the size of the fonts got totally wtf. Most fonts became huge in the OS windows/ program GUI objects. This made me panic and I thought I borked Ubuntu Studio already. I found a solution to return the state of the operating system back to its normal font size/icon sizes, but I then decided to come and ask for help on the forums, here , because I need help to install the nvidia graphics properly,
Thank you, many kind regards.

Comment: You never mentioned Ubuntu version and how you installed drivers.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply, It is the latest Ubuntu Studio version 22.04. I did it through browsing the internet and copy-pasting command line... I am relatively new to Linux , which is why I am asking for help.

Comment: Nice about linux , I found clipboard feature , so this is more or less what I copied and pasted

Comment: sudo nvidia-uninstall

sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf

echo 'nouveau' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop

sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf

sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'

dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia

sudo apt reinstall ubuntustudio-desktop-core

sudo apt reinstall ubuntustudio-desktop-core ubuntustudio-desktop

sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

Comment: Also let you know , I have autism diagnosis , so I find communication difficult , and also I don't know why this forum put all the copied and pasted commands on a single line

Comment: This is a wrong way to install drivers. The correct one is either using Software & Updates or by `sudo ubuntu-drivers install`. You ran a lot of incorrect commands. I suggest reinstalling the system to start from scratch.

Comment: Oh no , you are kidding me ? reinstalling system. The chap at the shop installed it and I don't have the installation disk... this isn't helpful

Comment: So I I have to make an installation DVD , reinstall ... christ.. :( my worst nightmare has come true

Comment: So downloaded the iso , make the dvd, and do the reinstall. I would come back after that. It is probably going to do the giant font stuff again.